# No process is on the other end of the pipe

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I am querying a SQL Server 2008 database using `SqlDataReader`. Data I'm expecting is millions of records and almost 400 GB of data. But after almost 90% of the data is fetched successfully, I get an exception

> A transport-level error has occurred
>   when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on
>   the other end of the pipe.)

How could this exception come in the middle of the process?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the connection may be timing out or possibly connections are running out on the server.
Are you opening multiple connections?
Maybe post a code snippet.